# Intellij IDEA has changed EVERY description in all classes. How? And how to avoid this "feature"?

Tags: intellij-idea

I checked out the project from a Git repository inside Intellij IDEA. All the files are now blue (modified).

A quick investigation shows that all the (automatic) comments were translated, like here:

`git diff Login.java`

```
 /**
- * <p>Java-Klasse für login complex type.
+ * <p>Java class for login complex type.
  *
- * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
+ * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
  *
...
```

It is a cool feature, but how to turn it OFF permanently?

(Intellij IDEA 2021.2)

Comment: It looks like some third-party plug-in or git hook. IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have this feature.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Indeed. This time it was: Apache CXF. Thanks for the suggestive comment!